# Как сделать, чтобы при срабатывании скролла, произошла прокрутка от первого блока ко второму, а дальше обычный скролл был?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при срабатывании скролла, произошла прокрутка от первого блока ко второму, а дальше обычный скролл был?

в моем варианте скролл далее невозможен - возвращает в начало страницы

```js
var currentAnchor = 0;
var isAnimating  = false;

function scrollUpDown(dir) {

  var sections = $('#s1, #s2');
  var currentScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  var nearestEl = null;
  var defaultTop = 0;

  sections.each(function(i, el) {

    var el = $(el);

    if (dir == 'down') {
      if (currentScroll < el.offset().top) {
        if (nearestEl != null && nearestEl.offset().top > el.offset().top) {
          nearestEl = el;
        } else if (nearestEl == null) {
          nearestEl = el;
        }
      }
      defaultTop = $(document).outerHeight(true);
    }

    if (dir == 'up') {
      if (currentScroll > el.offset().top) {
        if (nearestEl != null && nearestEl.offset().top < el.offset().top) {
          nearestEl = el;
        } else if (nearestEl == null) {
          nearestEl = el;
        }
      }
      var defaultTop = 0;
    }

  });

  if (nearestEl != null) {
    return(nearestEl.offset().top);
  } else {
    return(defaultTop);
  }
}

$(function(){

  $('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if( isAnimating ) {
        return false;
    }
    isAnimating  = true;
    if( e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
      currentAnchor = scrollUpDown('up');
      console.log('вверх');
    } else {

      currentAnchor = scrollUpDown('down');
      console.log('вниз')
    }

    isAnimating  = true;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: currentAnchor
    }, 500, 'swing', function(){
        isAnimating  = false;
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#s1 {
  background-color: #ff8080;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#s1 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

p {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s1">
  Секция 1
  <a href="#s2">Вниз</a>
</div>
<div id="s2">
  Секция 2
  <a href="#s1">Вверх</a>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>
  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>
   
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>
    
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let $s1 = $('#s1'),
  $s2 = $('s2'),
  $scroll_btn = $('[data-js-scroll]'),
  scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop(),
  scroll_dir = getScrDir(), //определяем направление скрола
  scrolling = false; // происходит ли скроллинг? 

$(window).scroll((e) => {
  scroll_dir = getScrDir();
  scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

  let s1_offset_top = $s1.offset().top,
    s1_height = $s1.height(),
    full_offset = s1_offset_top + s1_height;

  if (scroll_dir === 'bottom' && scroll_position < full_offset && !scrolling) {
    animateScroll(full_offset);
  } else if (scroll_dir === 'top' && scroll_position < full_offset && !scrolling) {
    animateScroll(s1_offset_top);
  }
})

$scroll_btn.click((e) => {
  let $this = $(e.currentTarget),
    target = $this.data('target'),
    $target = $('[data-anchor="' + target + '"]');

  if ($target.length) {
    let target_affset_top = $target.offset().top;
    animateScroll(target_affset_top);
  }
})

function animateScroll(scroll_pos) {
  scrolling = true;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: scroll_pos
  }, 500, 'swing', function() {
    scrolling = false;
  });
}

function getScrDir() {
  curren_position = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (curren_position > scroll_position) {
    return 'bottom';
  } else {
    return 'top';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#s1 {
  background-color: #ff8080;
}

a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#s1 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

p {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s1" data-anchor="first">
  Секция 1
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-js-scroll data-target="second">Ко второму</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-js-scroll data-target="threed">К третьему</a>
</div>
<div id="s2" data-anchor="second">
  Секция 2
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-js-scroll data-target="first">Вверх</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-js-scroll data-target="threed">К третьему</a>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

</div>
<div id="s3" data-anchor="threed">
  Секция 2
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-js-scroll data-target="first">Вверх</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-js-scroll data-target="second">Ко второму</a>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, minima, quae. Nemo iste eveniet necessitatibus quas deleniti. Et deleniti nemo hic delectus minus quia, incidunt laudantium consequuntur, harum dolorem reiciendis.</p>

</div>
```